# Show only duplicate values

Tags: postgresql, duplication

How to select rows with duplicate values (non-distinct rows) and summarize with a count of the number of duplicate values in order of the most frequent duplicates?

Given a table of:

- `person_`

  - `name_`
  - `favorite_color_`

…with this data:

```
Bob       Brown
Lucy      Lavender
Orin      Orange
Liam      Lavender
Betty     Brown
Blair     Brown
```

…show:

```
3         Brown
2         Lavender
```

We omit “Orange” from the list as it is distinct, with no duplicate siblings.

I am most interested in Postgres, but I expect this can be done in standard SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can be done with a simple [`SELECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) statement.

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_ , favorite_color_ 
FROM person_ 
GROUP BY favorite_color_
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY count_ DESC
;
```

The `count(*)` command is an [aggregate function supported by Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) and gives the number of rows with duplicate values in a column specified by the [`GROUP BY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) clause.

To omit the values without any duplicates, add the [`HAVING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-HAVING) clause. A `HAVING` is similar to a `WHERE` but applies to each row being generated to represent the grouping.

To get results to sort with most frequent duplicate values at the top, use the [`ORDER BY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) clause. We reference the column alias `count_` that we created in the first line with the `AS` clause.